# Why is fetchedResultsController set to nil?

Tags: core-data, ios4

Why is this in the FetchedResultsController code that Apple gives us?

```
if (fetchedResultsController != nil) {
    return fetchedResultsController;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because they only need to set up the `fetchedResultsController` once.

Below that statement there is a load of set up to `initialise` `fetchedResultsController`.

So the first time you hit the method by calling `fetchedResultsController` the ivar is set up then any subsequent calls to `fetchedResultsController` simply return the already set up ivar.